# Align cell text to the bottom of the cell

Tags: latex

I have the following text:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Text 1      & \multirow{3}{*}{\hspace{8.5cm}\includegraphics[scale=1]{"Images/picture".pdf}} \\
Text 2 &                        \\
Text 3                   &                       
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It contains 2 columns. The left column contains 3 cells and the right column contains just 1 cell with an image.

I want the text on the left column to align **at the bottom** with the image in the right column.

I have tried using b{5cm}, etc. from the array package but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the stacked items in the first column in its own `tabular` that you can align to the `[b]`aseline:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} l @{} l }
    \begin{tabular}[b]{ l }
      Text 1 \\
      Text 2 \\
      Text 3
    \end{tabular} &
    \includegraphics[height=5\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```